# Thousand separator conditioned by next word with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add a thousand separator (e.g ",") to large numbers in a given string conditioned by the next word. 
This regex works for any number :

```
re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))', r"\g<0>,", my_string)
```

But I only want to apply it for specific cases, this one is ok (euros/dollars) :

```
re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))', r"\g<0>,", "1000 euros")
> "1,000 euros"
```

This one isn't :

```
re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))', r"\g<0>,", "n° 1234 f")
> "n° 1,234 f"
```

How to properly add a condition ?
Thanks

Comment: Try adding a negative lookbehind `(?<!n° )\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`  https://regex101.com/r/Ndzddy/1 See https://ideone.com/uX0HfN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the group of words you want to apply the change to in the lookahead e.g.

```
\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+\s*(euros|dollars))
```

In python:

```
print(re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+\s*(euros|dollars))', r"\g<0>,", "1000 euros"))
print(re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+\s*(euros|dollars))', r"\g<0>,", "n° 1234 f"))
print(re.sub(r'\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+\s*(euros|dollars))', r"\g<0>,", "1234567 dollars"))
```

Output:

```
1,000 euros
n° 1234 f
1,234,567 dollars
```